# application requires an updatable query

Tags: asp, dsn

While making programme on ASP and connecting the data to database and connecting it with DSN,the browser says that application requires an updateable query..
please help

Answer (score 0):

This depends heavily on which version of the OLE DB you're using, but a good place to start is (a) [Microsoft's KB](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/175168), and (b) [Google](http://www.google.com/search?q=asp+operation+must+use+an+updateable+query).